# Matching multiple parts of a string as first match

Tags: ruby, regex

Given the following string:

`details.html?id=8220&inr=4241&marke=Ford&modell=Focus&art=Gebrauchtwagen&standort=`

I need to match `82204241` in a single expression. I need to extract all numbers from it as a single match. Any idea how this can be solved?

`(\d+)` will create two matches. I also tried with something like this without any luck: `details\.html\?[id=|.*inr=]+(\d+)`

Comment: Join the matched results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex only matches a substring of the original string. Since `82204241` does not appear as a substring in the original string, it is impossible to match that as a single match with a regex.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 0):

How about joining regex scan? Here:

```
a = "details.html?id=8220&inr=4241&marke=Ford&modell=Focus&art=Gebrauchtwagen&standort="
a.scan(/\d+/).join
# => "82204241"
```

Comment: Thx for the response. It is of course possible to do that, but in this particular case all I have access to is the regular expression.